# R <-> JS: loop over XML nodes and return getComputedStyle values to dataframe

Tags: javascript, r

In a nutshell, I want to write some code that will take in a URL and return a dataframe with this page's HTML elements and their CSS values. Now my major problem is finding a way to make JS and R communicate.

At this point, I need to mention that I have a limited coding knowledge (i'm a marketer). I learn R and need to use it to complete the task.

I've found that "getComputedStyle" is the JS function I need, but the page must be open in the browser to return the actual computed styles.

Thus, I've come up with a solution below:

Creating some simple Chrome plugin that would send the current site's URL to R, R would create a list of XML node paths and in a loop, using querySelector and getComputedStyle, populate a dataframe with the CSS values returned by the plugin.

However, I don't know how to make JS and R communicate.

I need to make it work for me only so should I somehow run R on localhost (I use Mac OS)? And then what?

I've read a little about OpenCPU but am not sure if that's what I need.

Or maybe there's some other solution?

Comment: Instead of inventing the wheel, have you looked at the rvest and/or the XML package.  They can read the url and then parse out the xml tags.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I'm concerned, none of those functions return full list of actual, finally computed by the browser styles. Only those specified for the class/id etc. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you look instead into [RSeenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) which lets you run a headless webserver in R

Comment: Ok, will look into it but seems like it'll be a lot to wrap my head around.